# Connection Timeout while running sql procedure from servlet

Tags: java, sql-server, servlets

I want to run a procedure which takes approx 15 minutes to run in sql environment. Whereas when I am trying to run it using Servlet I am getting Network error(TCP error). I am using Http Server using ajp to transfer request to Tomcat server. This is my code. can anybody tell me what is going wrong here.

```
    import com.itech.softensity.utils.Utils;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.sql.CallableStatement;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

    public class JdbcServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
    protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JdbcServlet.class);
    static final String jtdsurl =  "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<server_name>;instance=<instance>;DatabaseName=<databasename>;socketTimeout=100000;socketKeepAlive=true";
    static final String USER = "username";
    static final String PASS = "password";

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException
{
    Connection con = null;
    CallableStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet result =null;
    try
    {
    Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");

    logger.info("Connecting to database...");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(jtdsurl, "username","password");
    logger.info("Creating statement...");
    String sql = "exec populateMobRefLit";
    stmt = con.prepareCall(sql);
    stmt.setQueryTimeout(100000);
    stmt.executeQuery();
    logger.info("Executing stored procedure check new...");
    if(stmt != null){
    stmt.close();
    }
    if(con != null){
    con.close();
    }
      logger.info("Procedure run successfully values: ");
    }
   catch (Exception e) {

    try {
          if(stmt != null){
          stmt.close();
          }
          if(con != null){
          con.close();
          }
    }catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
      logger.info(Utils.stackTraceToString(e));
   }
   finally{

    try {
          if(stmt != null){
          stmt.close();
          }
          if(con != null){
          con.close();
          }
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
 }
```

I have tried it with JTDS driver as well as microsoft provided jdbc driver as the drivers have specific timeouts. I have tried Hibernate, I have tried Spring, but nothing works.

Comment: If the SQL statement completed quicker (in a couple of seconds), does your code work? It does sound like it is a browser timeout and not an SQL connection issue!?

Comment: yes when I run for lesser number of records it works fine.

Comment: Is that code really complete? I'm not seeing where the actual execution happens - did you trim out too much code?

Comment: only executeQuery() I missed, Else it is working

Comment: Also, post the complete error message that you are getting ... maybe there is more information in it?

Comment: There is no error message coming in logs. Only TCP error is coming in browser.

Comment: That would suggest that it is a browser timeout and has nothing to do with the SQL statement. Try increasing the page timeout in our webserver (Tomcat?).